# Android device FPS calculation

Tags: android, frame-rate, surfaceflinger, dumpsys

I'm was using [gfxinfo](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/performance) for calculating the app FPS, but apparently that does not work with games, as they don't use UIKit for drawing.
I tried to use SurfaceFlinger, but somehow it does not provide any frame information, only gives a refresh period. 
The question is, how can I calculate the app and game FPS on Android device using adb command?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: did you ever find answer to this problem